# Issue with advanced MySQL LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query below. There is multiple rows in the "stats" table with the username. 1 for each server(s). It keeps duplicating the kills & deaths value based on the amount of rows there are in the stats table with the username. For instance if there are 2 kills and 1 death in the pvp table for the username Test and there is 2 rows in the stats table with the username Test one for server1 and one for server2, then when running this query it shows 4 kills and 2 deaths. I dont know why.

Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7049/1

```
SELECT st.*, 
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.killer = st.username), 0) AS kills,
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.username = st.username), 0) as deaths,
COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(pvp.killer = st.username) / SUM(pvp.username = st.username), 2), 0.00) 
as kd FROM stats AS st 
LEFT JOIN pvp ON pvp.username = st.username OR pvp.killer = st.username 
WHERE st.username="Username"
```

Comment: Please post your sample data and the desired output. Or, even better, create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your problem.

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7049/1

Comment: One more step. What outcome (result) should such query produce?  What do you consider right? Please post in table form.

Comment: I dont know what table form is.

Comment: I want it to show an total amount of kills & deaths from the pvp table correctly.

Comment: OK. Forget the table format. If 4 kills and 2 deaths is incorrect, just tell us the #s that you want to get. Is it **2** and **1**?

Comment: Yes sir it is 2 kills 1 deaths.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up servers details so you probably need `AND(st.server = pvp.server)` in your query (in the JOIN condition)

```
SELECT st.id,st.username,st.balance,st.xplevel,st.server,
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.killer = st.username), 0) AS kills,
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.username = st.username), 0) as deaths,
COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(pvp.killer = st.username) / SUM(pvp.username = st.username), 2), 0.00) 
as kd
 FROM stats AS st 
LEFT JOIN pvp ON (pvp.username = st.username OR pvp.killer = st.username)
              AND(st.server = pvp.server)
WHERE st.username="tacoboboy32"
GROUP BY st.id,st.username,st.balance,st.xplevel,st.server
```

Also if you don't use GROUP BY you'll only get one row, so just group by every field in st. and it'll give you different information for each server.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7049/17/0)

Answer (score 0):

This is because a LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left hand half of the query, so you'll get a result for every stats line.

Try this:

```
SELECT stats.*, 
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.killer = stats.username), 0) AS kills,
COALESCE(SUM(pvp.username = stats.username), 0) as deaths,
COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(pvp.killer = stats.username) / SUM(pvp.username = stats.username), 2), 0.00) 
as kd 
FROM pvp  
LEFT JOIN stats ON pvp.username = stats.username OR pvp.killer = stats.username 
WHERE stats.username="Username"
```

This is actually a not bad guide http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: It says `Unknown table 'st'`

Comment: @user3205106 that's because I removed the AS from stats, editing it now.

Comment: Its still doing the same issue as the first query. Doubles.

Comment: @user3205106 Without seeing your schema, it's hard to diagnose hence, I have provided a guide, and an option.  I would suggest running it through a visual tool such as mysql workbench where you can view what is being returned by the query, and diagnose that way.